# How to add a shape behind an responsive image with css?

Tags: html, css

How would i go with making a drop shadow like this one [(picture link here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06QDZ.png)? Ive tried using Pseudo Element but that didnt work with all of my code. Im not finished with everything but this problem is really bugging me.

```
 <div class="header">
        <div class="flexcontainer">
            <img id="image" src="CV-PP-2.jpg" alt="">
        <h1>Samira Hadid</h1>
        </div>
        <h3>Full-Stack Web Developer</h3>
      </div>
```

```
.flexcontainer{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    align-items:center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 #image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    
}
```

I also need it to follow with the picture since it needs to be responsive.

Comment: `How would i go with making a drop shadow like this one?` - like which one?

Comment: Can you please put more detail like what and which image? so we can try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a pseudo-element:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100dvh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  position:relative;
}

.img:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: -100vmax 0 50%;
  background: chocolate;
  z-index: -1;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you man! I found something similar before and i didnt get it to work, but this made it work! I am very gratetful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This ....

```css
#image {
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this I hope you are looking for this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/drop-shadow

```
filter: drop-shadow(30px 10px 4px #4444dd);
```

Comment: Almost! as in the picture i linked, the image is round and the drop shadow is a square that goes up to the top of the container behind it. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for the link!